# How do you lazy load a package with `@angular-devkit/build-angular`

Tags: angular, angular-builder

How do I configure my `angular.json` to lazyload an SDK+jQuery on runtime?

I currently have the following to load "normally":

```
// package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.1",
    "@angular/pwa": "~0.802.1",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.1",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^8.2.1",
    "@capacitor/android": "^1.5.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^1.5.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "^1.5.0",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^1.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-audio": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@zoomus/websdk": "^1.7.8",
    "angular-pipes": "^9.0.2",
    "angularfire2": "^5.4.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "dayjs": "1.8.0",
    "firebase": "^7.14.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.1",
    "howler": "^2.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "minimist": "^1.2.5",
    "npm": "^6.14.4",
    "rxjs": "6.5.2",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.803.27",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.27",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^8.2.1",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^8.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.1",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^8.1.0",
    "@commitlint/config-angular": "^8.1.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/node": "12.0.0",
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.2.10",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "husky": "^1.3.1",
    "ts-node": "~8.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.16.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
```

```
// angular.json

            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "./node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/lib/",
                "output": "./node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/lib/"
              },
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/css/react-select.css",
            ],
```

But because of a strange dependency problem, I have to load `jquery` manually in my `index.html`

```
core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: $ is not defined
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (zoomus-websdk.umd.min.js:2)
```

```
// index.html
<head>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

What I would like to do is to include all the assets in my build, but only load `jquery`, `zoomus-websdk.umd.min.js` and dependencies when the user tries to join a zoom meeting.

I tried variations of the following, but even though the bundles get built, the sdk keeps getting included with the original page load.

```
// angular.json
            "scripts":[
              {
                "input": "./node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/zoomus-websdk.umd.min.js",
                "lazy": true,
                "bundleName": "lazy-zoom-sdk"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
                "lazy": true,
                "bundleName": "lazy-zoom-css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/css/react-select.css",
                "lazy": true,
                "bundleName": "lazy-zoom-css"
              }
            ]
```

I'm not even certain where/when `zoomus-websdk.umd.min.js` is explictly added to the project, but I assume it's from `package.json`

Comment: Can you post your complete package.json. Seems there is some version incompatibility which led to dependency problem, and hence you have to opt for manual route which caused all this.

Comment: I can do that. but the dependency goes away when I load the SDK + jquery manually before joining a meeting